# xcode 7.3 custom image is grayed out in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode7.3

I added custom image to to assets.xcassets as 3x in xcode project. It shows fine. 
Next, I added the iage to Tab Bar Item by selecting system item as custom and selected image as custom image. Also populated Bar Item image by selecting custom image.

In my storyboard, the image icon is completely grayed out in both the Tab Bar Item and Bar Item.

The image was created in Gimp as transparent image size scaled to 75x75

Can someone tell me how to fix this?
[image: aimage in assets.xcassets]
[image: setting custom image on tab bar]

Comment: A screenshot would probably help. There are LOTS of "greyed out" things in Xcode, including Size Classes stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @luiyezheng said, this is caused by the image rendering mode.
A better way to apply the rendering mode to all items in your TabBar will be to put this code in your TabBarController viewDidLoad method:

```
 for item in self.tabBar.items! {
            item.image = item.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
            item.selectedImage = item.selectedImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
        }
```

Comment: My tab bar controller is initial view controller. There is no TabBarController.swift. so added the code to ViewController.swift viewDidLoad method. Does not work. for item in (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items!)!{
            item.image = item.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
            
       }

Comment: You need to create a new class that inherit UITabBarViewController and assign that class to the tabbarcontroller in Storyboard

Comment: Thank you, Yes, the images shows up now in the tab bar. But when I select the bar item, blue color covers the entire icon and it does not show any text inside the icon as the text inside the icon also gets covered by blue color. So looks like the contents inside my icon like text is not created properly. Can you please tell me what settings I should use in creating the icon.

Comment: You should post another question then. Like "tab bar text invisible after setting custome icon image"

Answer (score 0):

After iOS7, you can set whether a UIImage render using tint color of current view with `imageWithRenderingMode`:

**AlwaysOriginal**

> Always draw the original image, without treating it as a template.

**AlwaysTemplate**

> Always draw the image as a template image, ignoring its color
>   information.

**Automatic**

> Use the default rendering mode for the context where the image is
>   used.

So what you want is:

```
self.barItem.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

By set renderingMode to `AlwaysOriginal`, the UIImage will always draw the original image and won't apply the template. Then you can get what you want.

Good luck:-)